# Table spacing in Outlook HTML e-mails

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, signature

First of all, before any of you marks this post as duplicate, please check my code if the solution isn't implemented yet.

OK, so I've been trying to resolve this issue for what's now close to three weeks and still can't wrap my head around it.
I'm trying to make an HTML signature for a company and I'm almost at the end of it. Becuase they require their own fonts to be used, I use image slices in nested tables.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W40e.png]

Although when I send the signature from Outlook to Outlook, it looks pretty much the way it should, opening it in any web mail service shows it with additional spacing and the table cells larger than intended:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2sPi.png]

What's going on is actually well visible when I select the whole table in the browser:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxmIF.png]

I've tried every possible thing to make it right, but so far nothing has helped me. 
Here's my code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse !important;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
<img src="images/uni_1.png" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important;" alt="Logo Dekre" border="0" valign="top"/>
</td>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
<table width="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse !important;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
<img width="140" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important;" src="images/uni_2.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
<a href="mailto:mailovaadresa">
<img width="140" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important;" src="images/uni_3.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0" />
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
<a href="http://www.dekre.cz/">
<img width="140" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important;" src="images/uni_4.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0" />
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<img src="images/zapati500.png" />
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in the code above, even the text parts are still images? If that's the case, why sliced this up at all? Why not just output one image? Guaranteed to render properly everywhere! On the other hand, if you'd like the text parts to render as HTML text, then the parts should be sliced up.

Comment: Yes, so it is. The signature is sliced up because I need the links clickable (see the **<a>** tags) and no other way was plausible in Outlook 2010 (e.g. empty cells and BG Image). Can't render the text parts as HTML text, because they use a custom font (mentioned in OP), which can't be included with the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the images need to be hosted somewhere (cloud, website, etc) to be able to be displayed when someone open your mail, since you cannot attach them every time in email content. I advise you to use plain text since some webmail services or even email client can block the images, therefore your contact informations may be suppressed (or make a text version beside the html one). Polices can be integrated in html mail (hosted remotely) but it will increase the mail size and the display as intended may not be guaranteed. Their font looks like Coda from Google...
Secondly, you need to define the height of the TD that host the image and then on the image (use inline style) try with style="max-height:XXpx" where XX is the same size as the TD that host the image (the height that you defined already).
Putting !important in inline style isn't mandatory since inline is the first to be executed no matter how many css and other rules are there.

Comment: Question: Why **max-height** instead of **height**?

Comment: Better leave html parsers do the math and limit the max height that they can use. Better, do the max-height on the td and nothing on the images, since your images will be always is the right size.

Comment: If this question refers to **Windows Outlook**, `max-height` [isn't supported](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/max-height/).

Comment: The answer is correct though, as I have set the **<td>**, **<tr>** and **<img>** heights fixed and all works well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is simple, you didn't add the height and width to all of your images. I guessed at the height of the image on the left (87px), set the three images on the right at a width of 140 and a height of 29 (87/3=29) and ran the results through Litmus.com. With the added height and widths for the images, single email client shows the signature in the same way.

Use this code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse !important;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
          <img height="87" width="43" src="images/uni_1.png" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important; background: yellow;" alt="Logo Dekre" border="0" valign="top" /> </td>
        <td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top"> 
        <table width="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse !important;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
                      <img width="140" height="29" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important; background: red;" src="images/uni_2.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top"> <a href="mailto:mailovaadresa">
                      <img width="140" height="29" style="Margin:0 !important;border:1 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important; background: green;" src="images/uni_3.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0" /> </a> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse:collapse !important;Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;vertical-align:top !important;" valign="top">
                      <a href="http://www.dekre.cz/">
                        <img width="140" height="29" style="Margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;padding:0 !important;display: block !important;vertical-align:top !important; background: blue;" src="images/uni_4.png" valign="top" alt="" border="0" /> </a> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As @Valentin R. mentions, you need to host the images somewhere. You can host them in the WordPress install on the domain. Copy those image paths to the code above and it will work everywhere.

Good luck with selling the smart walls.